# Watch app crashing with variable name "properties"

Tags: swift, crash, watchkit, wkinterfacecontroller

I've been debugging my watch app for a few hours now because every time I try to segue to a new interface controller, my app crashes after the return statement in `contextForSegueWithIdentifier`. I was getting an error 
saying `[__NSArrayM enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7967e280`and then the app would crash.

I ruled out the return statement for `contextForSegueWithIdentifier` and everything else. I had gotten to the point where I was commenting out single lines and rerunning to see what would work.

It turns out that in my new interface controller class I had a variable named `properties`. The line was `var properties = [String:AnyObject]()`. When I changed the variable name to anything else- my app stopped crashing and my new interface controller would instantiate fine.

Has anyone else run into this problem? I am thinking that there is a variable named `properties` somewhere else (maybe in WKInterfaceController?)? Can anyone confirm why a watch app crashes when you add a variable named properties?

Thank you in advance.